# Oil refil on large electrolytic capacitors

Tags: power-supply

This is related to capacitor construction.

Can a powerlytic or electrolytic capacitor (47,000 μF; 25 V DC) be refilled with oil after it released liquid via the safety gasket?

Assuming effects of overheating, loosing probably half the fluid?  And is the oil fluid in a capacitor miniral oil? Or with what type of oil can it be refilled?

The capacitor's size in question is roughly 100 mm high and  has 80 mm diameter.

Comment: Please spend 5 minutes rewriting your question into something coherent.

Comment: -1 for the very sloppy writing, and closing since I gave up halfway and therefore don't know what is being asked.  Disrespecting the volunteers here by dumping slop on them is not the way to get free help.

Answer (score 6):

Electrolytic capacitors are not filled with oil, rather they are filled with (not surprisingly, perhaps) electrolyte*. You cannot repair such a capacitor once it has vented.

Oil is used for non-polar capacitors used on AC (sometimes) though film types have taken much of that market.

Oil-filled capacitor (from [this](https://www.tubeworld.com/) site):

[image]

The NO-PCB'S (sic) is not an admonition to avoid mounting the cap on a printed circuit board, but rather refers to the type of oil used, which is indicated to not contain  PolyChlorinated Biphenyls, a type of oil which works very well but has toxicity issues, especially when burned.

---

*The electrolyte is a conductive ionic liquid. From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminum_electrolytic_capacitor#Electrolyte) on electrolytic capacitors:

> The electrolytic systems used today can be roughly summarized into three main groups:
>
> 1. **Electrolytes based on ethylene glycol and boric acid.** 
>      In these so-called glycol or borax electrolyte an unwanted chemical crystal water reaction occurs according to the scheme: "acid + alcohol" gives "ester + water". These borax electrolytes are standard electrolytes, long in use, and with a water content between 5 and 20%. They work at a maximum temperature of 85 °C or 105 °C in the entire voltage range up to 600 V. Even with these capacitors, the aggressiveness of the water must be prevented by appropriate measures.
> 2. **Almost anhydrous electrolytes based on organic solvents, such as dimethylformamide (DMF), dimethylacetamide (DMA), or γ-butyrolactone (GBL).** These capacitors with organic solvent electrolytes are suitable for temperature ranges from 105 °C, 125 °C or 150 °C, have low leakage current values and have very good long-term capacitor behavior.
> 3. **Water based electrolytes with high water content**, up to 70% water for so-called "low-impedance", "low-ESR" or "high-ripple-current" electrolytic capacitors with rated voltages up to 100 V for low-cost mass-market applications. The aggressiveness of the water for aluminum must be prevented with suitable additives.

Proprietary additives are very important, as evidenced by the [Great Capacitor Plague](https://www.eetimes.com/author.asp?doc_id=1329037) of the early 21st century.

Comment: *"Holy coulombs Batman, 6 MegaFarads?"*  For those that haven't seen really old caps before, "MFD" stands for MicroFaraD, not Mega.

Answer (score 2):

THis is not constructed the same as oil filled transformers, such as **Nynas** brand. They use chemcial acids and anodic oxides.

Both are highly processed and refined in purity to remove contaminants that lead to leakage and breakdown.  The higher the storage density, generally , the greater challenge to quality control of each material, process and design.

[Basics of a capacitor](http://www.elna.co.jp/en/capacitor/alumi/principle.html)
MSDS [Safety sheet example](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjYxqTVuozZAhWqtVkKHYwpB1kQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.illinoiscapacitor.com%2Fpdf%2FPapers%2FMaterial%2520Safety%2520Data%2520Sheet%2520AL%2520lytics.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0abx_ibux5tI6J3wjTNGcP)

It's not easy to make good quality capacitors, demonstrated only by a few Japanese companies with rigorous quality control processes.

The current flow is determined by the  foil gap and voltage in V/um , leakage of particles and heat generated which adds more energy to accelerate the particles. We call this a thermal runnaway.  Your failure indicates a thermal runaway effect producing more contaminants and heat so even if you had the right fluid the electric field stress would cause similar failure immediately.

Electrolytic Capacitors are similar to Electrolytic batteries which all use toxic chemicals including batteries made of Alkaline, LIthium Ion, Ni-Cad, Lead Acid.  This is why they should be disposed of safely so as not to contaminate every dump site.